# How to calculate key length in bits?

Tags: public-key, keys

On a technical forum discussion, an example key of 16 hexadecimal numbers was said to be 2048 bits in length. I do not understand this as each number would be 4 bytes - 32 bits - therefore to me 16 numbers would be 512 bits. I am sure I have misread something so any clarification would really help. This question may be too simple but I can't stand confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> An example key of 16 hexadecimal numbers was said to be 2048 bits in length

If the key is expressed as 16 hexadecimal *digits*, then that's 16×4 = 64 bits.

If the key is expressed as 16 hexadecimal *numbers* each 4 bytes, then that's 16×4×8 = 512 bits.

If the key is 2048-bit and expressed as 16 hexadecimal *numbers* (of equal size) then each number is 2048/16 = 128 bits.

Beware that this is about the bit size of the *expression* of a particular key, which may or may not be what's called the "key length" or "key size", especially for asymmetric cryptography.

Often, the form in which a key is expressed uses more bits than the designated key size. For example a typical "2048-bit" RSA key is often expressed as 294 bytes (2352 bits, 588 hexadecimal characters, 392 base-64 characters each coding 6 bits) because on top of 256 bytes for the public modulus there are 3 bytes for the public exponent, and some [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASN.1) decoration on top of that. See this [example standard RSA 2048-bit key](https://lapo.it/asn1js/#MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAmUmHj0kH2Eoa1UE2AStZGZ7PmcS24APuDQwOH_AL9mzVNFgGlP0GyDOZAbbHXyD6cRi6Lf359OnVReju1pXVfOsQ9gW3CII7VGNDKHz0XCz6BGxAK_aeoN0krnv8bU8GXjq6TeMIwwwRRh4PSPvmNZWjM537Gp3e-YfUvLd8jinkFGKLB1bGTlTZ4a4eIhxJlURF-12FUrDKcXW0uj8XcnhzIuXgYp63Mz_zB9Ccp-bay09ku2hh4z9DK3dydMdafcGRENBWlyfNtRRW2RiAHsPWKBiwG2owI4hpU0KxTOivTynBb_yTuimFHTLP7fKI8RA-KVj8T_BOUXD8mk_Q9QIDAQAB).

Sometime, the form in which a key is expressed uses less bits than it's designated key size in bits. For example, for RSA 2048-bit public keys, we could use the convention that $e=F_4=2^{(2^4)}+1=65537$, that the top 1024 bits for the public exponent are $\left\lfloor\pi\times2^{1022}\right\rfloor$, and express such keys as 128 bytes. For private keys, it's possible to express keys in a compact form a little below the designated *strength* in bits of the asymmetric scheme, using [key stretching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching). E.g. an ECDSA private key for a 256-bit elliptic curve like secp256k1 can easily fits 14 bytes without loss of security, when the public key is hard to compress to much less than 30 bytes.

Comment: Many thanks again for your detailed reply. It is a lot more complicated than I originally thought and I have been reading up on the links you provided. For some reason I thought it would be as easy as calculating password length.